# Loading CSV using "fast and simple csv library"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file, csv

I am trying to load a csv file using following lib: [Fast and Simple csv lib in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685310/Simple-and-fast-CSV-library-in-Csharp?msg=4732529#xx4732529xx)
I followed example and did following:

- Created a class with headers as public peoperties. Eg: One of the header in csv is type. So in class called `csvHeaders` i declared `publicstring type{get; set;}`
- Tried printing the entries in csv by:

```cs
foreach (var c in CsvFile.Read<csvHeaders>(filePath) )
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.ActivityID);
}
```

Any idea why I am not getting anything? (Please refer to the lib for once)

Comment: That library uses a ; as the field separator...

Comment: @Adrian I had changed the FieldSeparator to ',' rather than ';'. Any clues why I can't get it working?

Comment: have you a sample of the data you are trying to load?

Comment: @Adrian I got it. You are right, one of the issues was default ';'. Apart from that one class needed some changes. Thanks a lot.